# Rails - Permission denied - /home/rails/tmp/cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, permissions, unicorn, assets

Whenever I try to load a page with the 'mercury' editor stylesheet I get:

```
Started GET "/" for 84.73.28.228 at 2014-05-07 10:56:38 +0000
Processing by StaticController#index as HTML
  Rendered layouts/_socialmedia.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered static/index.html.erb within layouts/application (6.8ms)
  Rendered layouts/_menu.html.erb (1.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (1.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_analytics.html.erb (0.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 29ms (Views: 17.5ms | ActiveRecord: 1.3ms)
Started GET "/editor/" for 84.73.28.228 at 2014-05-07 10:56:41 +0000
Processing by MercuryController#edit as HTML
  Rendered text template within layouts/mercury (0.0ms)
Compiled jquery-1.7.js  (4ms)  (pid 26385)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 100ms

ActionView::Template::Error (Permission denied - /home/rails/tmp/cache/assets/D5E):
    5:     <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    6:     <title>Mercury Editor</title>
    7:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'mercury' %>
    8:     <%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery-1.7', 'mercury' %>
    9:   </head>
    10:   <body>
    11:     <script type="text/javascript">
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:245:in `mkdir'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:245:in `fu_mkdir'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:219:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:217:in `reverse_each'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:217:in `block in mkdir_p'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:203:in `each'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:203:in `mkdir_p'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/cache/file_store.rb:161:in `ensure_cache_path'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/cache/file_store.rb:90:in `write_entry'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:140:in `write_entry'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/cache.rb:364:in `block in write'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/cache.rb:520:in `instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/cache.rb:362:in `write'
  sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/caching.rb:90:in `cache_set'
  sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/caching.rb:53:in `cache_set_hash'
  sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/caching.rb:24:in `cache_asset'
  sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/index.rb:92:in `build_asset'
  sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/base.rb:169:in `find_asset'
  sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/index.rb:60:in `find_asset'
  sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:16:in `initialize'
  sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/base.rb:252:in `new'
  sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/base.rb:252:in `build_asset'
  sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `block in build_asset'
  sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/caching.rb:19:in `cache_asset'
  sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/index.rb:92:in `build_asset'
  sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/base.rb:169:in `find_asset'
  sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/index.rb:60:in `find_asset'
  sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/base.rb:177:in `[]'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/sprockets/helpers/rails_helper.rb:162:in `rewrite_extension'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_view/asset_paths.rb:26:in `compute_public_path'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/sprockets/helpers/rails_helper.rb:56:in `asset_path'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/sprockets/helpers/rails_helper.rb:32:in `block in javascript_include_tag'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/sprockets/helpers/rails_helper.rb:26:in `collect'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/sprockets/helpers/rails_helper.rb:26:in `javascript_include_tag'
  mercury-rails (0.9.0) app/views/layouts/mercury.html.erb:8:in `__usr_local_rvm_gems_ruby_______p____gems_mercury_rails_______app_views_layouts_mercury_html_erb__3694222398901886890_33552740'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:125:in `instrument'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:59:in `render_with_layout'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:45:in `render_template'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:18:in `render'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:36:in `render_template'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:17:in `render'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:110:in `_render_template'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:225:in `_render_template'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:103:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:28:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/compatibility.rb:50:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:88:in `render'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in render'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `block in ms'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/benchmark.rb:296:in `realtime'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `ms'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block in render'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:83:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:24:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:39:in `render'
  mercury-rails (0.9.0) app/controllers/mercury_controller.rb:9:in `edit'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:425:in `_run__4116608381698480854__process_action__2358713743569235138__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
  activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:601:in `call'
  railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:601:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__3113844860461911926__call__1767113983053102621__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
  railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
  railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
  railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
  unicorn (4.7.0) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:580:in `process_client'
  unicorn (4.7.0) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:660:in `worker_loop'
  unicorn (4.7.0) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:527:in `spawn_missing_workers'
  unicorn (4.7.0) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:153:in `start'
  unicorn (4.7.0) bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

I've tried
`chown -R rails:rails /home/rails`. 
I've tried deleting tmp and recreating it.
I've tried precompiling assets and clearing the chache. I've tried increasing the asset version.
Database acess works fine. This all happens in a production environment. I've given my rails user root privileges, everything, but he doesn't want to quit complaining.

I use the digital ocean rails droplet, it has nginx with unicorn.

Any ideas?
I have none on where to begin...

Comment: Can you try this  sudo chown -R  /var/www/appname/

Comment: @CaffeineCoder Tried it too, still throws the exact error at me

Comment: @CaffeineCoder Nevermind, a combination of power cycling re-logging and what you said got me a new error `ActionView::Template::Error (jquery-1.7.js isn't precompiled):`. I'll keep on fixing hopefully.

Comment: Glad i cloud help , but remember the command opens up the app to all users . I suggested it so that you could find the actual error , be sure to restrict permissions on it after you are done solving it :)

Answer (score 0):

After chown-ing some more directories, I finally get another error:
`ActionView::Template::Error (jquery-1.7.js isn't precompiled):`.

Exclusively adding this to the asset pipeline; Then on precompiling assets it gave me: `Command failed with status ()`.

So it turns out the default rails droplet provided by digital ocean is 64 bit with 500mb RAM, which causes rails to do all these weird things because it can't breathe. Doing my own thing from a 34 bit distro solved the problem.